# Show $\int_0^\pi\sin^2(n\theta/2)^{-1/n}d\theta=\int_0^\pi\sin^2(\theta)^{-1/n}d\theta$

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, definite-integrals

I believe the answer might involve some periodicity argument, but I am unable to make one work. Any insights are appreciated!

This integral is motivated by the second part of the question from this post: [Conformal map from unit disk to polygon](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/607484/conformal-map-from-unit-disk-to-polygon)

Following User's advice, I have
$$\int_0^{2\pi}\sin^2(n\theta/2)^{-1/n}\ d\theta=n\int_0^{2\pi/n}\sin^2(n\theta/2)^{-1/n}\ d\theta$$
Then I make the substitution $\varphi=n\theta/2$ with $d\varphi=n/2\ d\theta$ to get
$$\int_0^{2\pi}\sin^2(n\theta/2)^{-1/n}\ d\theta=n\cdot\frac{2}{n}\int_0^{\pi}\sin^2(\varphi)^{-1/n}\ d\varphi=2\int_0^{\pi}\sin^2(\varphi)^{-1/n}\ d\varphi.$$
Thus,
$$\int_0^{\pi}\sin^2(n\theta/2)^{-1/n}\ d\theta=\frac{1}{2}\left(2\int_0^{\pi}\sin^2(\varphi)^{-1/n}\ d\varphi\right)=\int_0^{\pi}\sin^2(\varphi)^{-1/n}\ d\varphi$$
as I wished to show. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:

Your guess is completely correct, if $n$ is assumed to be an integer number. 
Indeed $\sin^2\left(\frac\theta2\right)$ is an even $2\pi$-periodic function. Therefore 
$$
\int_0^\pi F(\sin^2(\theta/2))d\theta=\int_{m\pi}^{(m+1)\pi} F(\sin^2(\theta/2))d\theta
$$
for any function $F(x)$ and any integer number $m$. It follows:
$$
\int_0^{n\pi} F(\sin^2(\theta/2))d\theta=n\int_0^\pi F(\sin^2(\theta/2))d\theta.
$$

Can you take it from here?